# Why in Ruby do uninitialized instance variables return nil, but uninitialized class variables raise an error?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, why does an uninitialized instance variable return `nil` while an uninitialized class variable raises a `NameError`?

Compare:

```
@some_uninitialized_variable # => nil
```

and:

```
@@some_uninitialized_class_variable # => NameError
```

Comment: While you're at it, uninitialized local variables also return a name error.

Comment: @Jon, I think econom knows that. He wants to know `why?'

Comment: Flagged Jon's comment as not constructive.

Comment: @Jon, "I can't say I support that decision." is a little like saying, "I am not in favour of the decision that I be flogged". :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Actually no, they don't: `if false then foo = 42 end; foo # => nil`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I stand by my first comment, as `if false then foo = 42 end` initializes `foo` to `nil`. No?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The assignment is never evaluated. All it does is remove the ambiguity between local variables and a receiverless method call without arguments.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I would like to gain a better understanding of what's going on here. For example: `defined?(foo) #=> nil; if false then foo = 42 end; defined?(foo) => "local-variable"`. I understood that `foo` is initialize to `nil` by `foo = 42 if false` when it is parsed. The two expressions are equivalent and `defined?(foo) => "local-variable"` in both cases.  Does that not suggest that `foo` is initialized to `nil` when `if false then foo = 42 end` is parsed, even though `foo = 42` is not executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My take is the following:

- uninitialized local variables return a name error because Ruby doesn't know if its intended to be a local variable or a non-existent method.
- if uninitialized class variables returned `nil` when not defined, it could lead to nasty bugs when the variable was actually assigned the value `nil` by a distant ancestor. That is, I see this as protecting the coder.
- having instance variables default to `nil` when uninitialized if an oft-used feature: `@a = @a || []`.

Comment: 2) Could you provide some (pseudo-)code showing a uninitialized class variable a) return `nil` b) raise an error. 3) You mean often, right? I don't agree with you. You can use `a = a || []` (or `a ||= []`). So variable doesn't need to be set default to `nil` in order to use `||`/`||=`.

Comment: @DarekNędza, regarding 2), all I meant was that if unitialized class variables retuned `nil`, this could happen: `class Vikki; @@v = nil; end; class Herb < Vikki; end; class Me < Herb; def self.v_initted?; !!@@v; end; end; Me.v_initted? #=> false`. As to 3), we agree. I just meant that Ruby could not return `nil` from `puts a` when `a` is uninitialized, not knowing if `a` were intended to be a local variable or undefined method. I regret I cannot answer 1).

Comment: 2) You are checking if `@@v` is initialized. I expect `v_initted?` to return false or true. I would be very surprised if `v_initted?` have raised an error. In my opinion, protecting one coder (that use class variables - `@@var`) and not protecting other coder (that use instance variables - `@var`) is, at least, weird. 3) I am little confused. You mean something like this: ` x = x || puts(x)`?

Comment: if @@foo is not initialized, `@@foo = "bar"` won't work and gives an 'uninitialized class variable' error, but I'm wondering why  `@@foo ||= "bar"` does works. I thought the `||=` operator checks for nil, but in this case seems like it also initialise @@foo

Comment: @Paul, see [this explanation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s02.html) of uninitialized variables. Specifically, search for the word, “quirk”.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the way [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) works.

I am guessing here you are trying this in IRB. If you open up a prompt and enter `self` and `self.class`, you can see you are working on an `Object` called `main`.

But this does only answer the *where* part of the question (if there was any), not really the *why* part.